# mongoose find and update removes the other fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have schema like this:

```
this.schema = new Schema({
    userEmail: String
    environments: [
        {
            envId: String,
            appPreference: String,
            language: String,
            timeZone: String,
            summaryNotificationSchedule: {
                timeOfTheDay: String
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

**Update request:**

```
{
  "envId": "u2",
  "appPreference": "put2",
  "timeZone": "gmt",
  "summaryNotificationSchedule.timeOfTheDay": "32400",
}
```

As you can see, I am not sending   `"language": "abc",` in the update request and in the result I see the `language` field is removed. I want to update the fields but not remove the other fields

**Mongoose find and update call:**

```
await this.model.findOneAndUpdate({ userEmail, 'environments.envId': envId }, { $set: { 'environments.$': setPreferenceFields } }, { new: true });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create update object from your request first:

```js
let request = {
  "envId": "u2",
  "appPreference": "put2",
  "timeZone": "gmt",
  "summaryNotificationSchedule.timeOfTheDay": "32400",
};

let update = Object.keys(request).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[`environments.$.${cur}`] = request[cur];
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(update);
```

Then pass it to the update:

```
await this.model.findOneAndUpdate({ userEmail, 'environments.envId': envId }, { $set: update }, { new: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify property with parent key name of an array, it should be like this way,

```
await this.model.findOneAndUpdate(
    { 
        userEmail, 
        'environments.envId': envId
    }, 
    { 
        $set: { 
            'environments.$.envId': "u2", 
            'environments.$.appPreference': "put2",
            'environments.$.timeZone': "gmt",
            'environments.$.summaryNotificationSchedule.timeOfTheDay': "32400"
        } 
    }, 
    { new: true }
)
```

---

Another option, [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) start from MongoDB v4.2, this little lengthy process then above method,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `environments` array
- `$cond` check condition if `envId` is equal to matching envId then merge objects update objects and current objects using `$mergeObjects` otherwise return current object

```
await this.model.findOneAndUpdate(
    { userEmail },
    [
        {
            $set: {
                environments: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$environments",
                        in: {
                            $cond: [
                                {$eq: ["$$this.envId", envId]}, // add update id
                                {
                                    $mergeObjects: [
                                        "$$this",
                                        setPreferenceFields  // your update fields
                                    ]
                                },
                                "$$this"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    {new: true}
)
```

Comment: The incoming request is dynamic. We don't know the object contains all the fields or not. For example: environments.$.appPreference` might not be present in the object

Comment: you can do as per another answer by @Cuong, or you can use update with aggregation pipeline.using `$mergeOjects`, if you want i will provide an example of that.

Comment: Yes aggregation would help

Comment: just for the knowledge i have added update with aggregation pipeline option.