# How to update any amount of fields in a nested documen in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to update different fields of a nested array in Mongoose. Sometimes I will send runId and runStatus, some other times siteFetched and some other times siteInfo.

I have tried with the following code but the $set operator replaces the old fields.

The model:

```
campaignId: { type: String },
keywords: [{
            keyword: { type: String },
            serp: {
                runId: { type: String },
                runStatus: { type: String },
                siteFetched: { type: Boolean },
                sitesInfo: [{
                    title: { type: String },
                    url: { type: String },
                    description: { type: String },
                }],
            },
        },
    ],
```

Here is the code to update

```
  const campaign = await Campaign.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: campaignId, "keywords.keyword": keyword },
        {
            $set: { "keywords.$.apifySerp": {...serp }},
        }
    );
```

the value for serp varies like

```
 const serp = {
   runId: '1kLgbnvpADsDJyP1x',
   runStatus: 'READY'
 }
```

and

```
 const serp = {
        siteFetched: true
     }
```

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64061281/11711316

Comment: thanks. Solved with the help of the above thread.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that solved my problem.

```
const serp = {
    siteFetched: true,
};

let update = Object.keys(serp).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[`keywords.$.apifySerp.${cur}`] = serp[cur];
    return acc;
}, {});
```